# spring-mvc return raw json string

Tags: json, spring-mvc, gson

I want the convenience of automatically serializing objects into JSON and ability to return raw JSON string. I am using Gson instead of Jackson, since Gson has been in my app for a while and I have existing tweaks, converters, and annotations peppered throughout my app.

```
<mvc:annotation-driven >
<mvc:message-converters register-defaults="true">
          <bean class="com.test.GSONHttpMessageConverter" />   
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

I can automatically serialize pojo's:

```
@RequestMapping(value="foo/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Shop getShopInJSON(@PathVariable String name) {
    return new Shop();
}
```

I want this to work also:

```
@RequestMapping(value="rawJsonTest/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody String rawJsonTest(@PathVariable String name) {
    return "{\"test\":5}";

}
```

Result right now is an escaped value:

```
"{\"test\":5}"
```

instead of:

```
{"test":5}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your custom converter takes precedence over the default ones. It's thus called, considers the String as a raw String that must be converted to JSON, and thus escapes the double quotes.

I'm not sure if and how it's possible with XML to register a converter after (and not before) the default ones, but you could set register-defaults to false and provide an explicit list of all the converters you want to apply. If `org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter` is registered before your custom one, it will be called first and will send the returned String as is.

Comment: Ahh! Exactly. I didn't realize about the precedence in converters. I switched gson and String converters around in config file and now it works. Thank you @JB Nizet!!

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the correct answer, @JB Nizet

Order matters:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven >
<mvc:message-converters register-defaults="true">
    <bean class = "org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
               <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json; charset=UTF-8" />
        </bean>
        <bean class="com.test.GSONHttpMessageConverter" />  
    </mvc:message-converters>
```